# Is there a way to access entity value metadata in Watson Assistant using the JSON editor or SPEL

Tags: watson-assistant

I'm attempting to define some relationships between entity values, using metadata.

I've uploaded metadata to an entity value using the Watson API v1. When I list the entities through the same API I can see the metadata. I have not been able to access the metadata from Watson Assistant though.

As a test I changed the entity value and checked through Watson Assistant it was changed, so I know I'm working with the correct workspace. I've also checked the entity using the JSON editor to verify it was defined and tried assigning the entity to a context variable.

I've tried several methods including:
@Room.building, @Room.metadata.building, entities['Room']?metadata?.building, entities['Room']?.building (all within  the < ? tags). Using @Room and entities['Room']?.value returns the entity value correctly. It's accessing the metadata where it fails.

The metadata for building should not be returning null, but I"m either receiving a null or, depending on how I'm attempting to retrieve the value, a SPEL exception - no property on undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to access metadata defined on user entities in the `WA` runtime at this moment. The `metadata` are only returned when making the direct API call. You could use cloud functions call though to get the metadata in `WA` although that is not ideal either.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was afraid of. In some cases calling through the API may still be faster than the external system, so possibly a solution, if not ideal.